# Python web developement without using the Django stack?

Tags: python, web

I am trying to start web development with Python, but the vast majority of resources online are geared towards using the Django stack, is there a more simple library stack I can use to begin building some simple pages ?

To be more precise I don't want to tangle with the MVC pattern in Python at this time, is there a Python equivalent to  ASP.NET web forms or simple PHP non MVC sites ?

Solutions which would play well with the XAMPP stack would be a bonus but not a requirement.

Comment: Take a look at flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at:

- [flask](http://flash.pocoo.org)
- [bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org)
- [web.py](http://webpy.org)

they all are very decent python microframeworks.

For a list of many python frameworks, you can have a look at the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks)

*N.B.: I'm trying to be comprehensive to avoid framework troll that will flag this question as irrelevant*

About your `XAMPP` edit, you can achieve this using the `WSGI` entry point (which usually is the default), which is pretty standard and cross platform. I don't know much about `XAMPP` (except what's on wikipedia), but it looks really targeted at Perl+PHP.

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I missed that page.

Answer (score 1):

The Flask Mega Tutorial will help you build a Python site faster than anything else I've come across: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: Thank you for including a tutorial.